# Data warehouse - Star Schema Explained

Tags: schema, data-warehouse

I am Mapping a star schema from the start, and I have a question that I can't find an answer.

Picture that I have a model which involve **`Client, Store , Address, Time (Dimensions) and Sale (fact)`**. Ok, that is easy to model, but I get a "conceptual" question. I have to add a **`Newsletter`** Dimension to the star, and this **`newsletter`** can lead the **`customer`** to **`buy`** something.

So, in my report/cubes I need to know (in a period):

1. How many **`Newsletter`** lead to a **`Sale`**,
2. How many **`Newsletter`** have been generated.

Where should I place the generate_date of **`Newsletter`**? If i place it in FACT table, but if this **`Newsletter`** did not lead to a **`Sale`**, there will be no date in FACT table.

If i place it on **`Newsletter`** and join it to **`Time`**, I would be breaking the Star schema?

How do I solve this :S

I have many other cases that is the same question, like client join_date.

Comment: This should sound like obvious to someone, but still not clear for me. Anyone that have made a start schema can answer it easily (i guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood! Why your making **Sale** as a Dimension and **Store** as a Fact? Normally Fact table contains Transactional data and I think **Sale** is Transactional. But this is my assumption as you haven't described what type of data it contain.

As far as **Newsletter** is concerned! Yes you can add just like other dimensions you have added but to get desired result! You also have to add **Customer** Dimension.

Place **generate_date** in **Date** dimension and place **Date ID** in Fact table.

You cannot join **Newsletter** with **Time** as it will break Start Schema rules.

This [link](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2286) might be helpful to you.

Comment: I meant Sales as a fact table :) ... Placing a dateid por a dimension that May or May Not exist for this fact is a good idea? DOes this affect the querys somehow?

Comment: It depends on your scenario and requirement.

Comment: My point is, i need to analyse many forms of view, newsletter that lead to a sale, sales by month, new clients by month, etc. When is the time to create a new Star Schema? How should it be done?